# Horizontal listview/recyclerview/viewpager load more data on scroll to right

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Please help me to solve the below issue:

Using Viewpager:

1)First i will call service i will get 10 items set to adapter.
2)at 10 th position i need to call service again to load another 10 items.
3)Count is set to 50.
4)But adapter is getting cleared every time and loading only 10 items.

Using recyclerview with Layout manager as horizontal

1)Adapter inflated layout view items are displaced when i scroll from right to see load more where as working perfect for vertical.
Endless recyclerview

Using horizontal listview with on scroll listener interface.

Finally i want to implement 
Horizontal listview load more data on scroll to right .

http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html

from this link how i need to get onscroll liste
nere interface.
Thanks in advance
Rehana

Answer (score 0):

you should try the following code

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;
                    additems();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

in the additem() add the next 10 items to array list and set the flag_loading as false. and call notifydatasetchanged. it should work.